# What KVM matrix switch to buy for 2 computers and 2 monitors?

Tags: kvm

I am trying to find a KVM matrix switch to switch two computers with two monitors each between two sets of monitors and keyboards. This should be controllable by software. It should also be possible to control one PC from both sets of mouse and keyboard if possible. Display port or hdmi would be an option.

Any suggestions? I only find huge devices which are overpriced for this application or video signal switching only.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Something like this? https://www.scan.co.uk/products/aten-cs692-2-port-usb-hd-audio-video-kvm-switch

Comment: This switches two computers to one keyboard/monitor, what i need is a solution to have two computers switched to two sets of keyboard/monitor.

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of what you're after?

Comment: I found this: http://www.gefen.com/product/4x4-dvi-kvm-dual-link-matrix-EXT-DVIKVM-444DL, but it says no HDCP. Is this a problem with windows computers not running any content with copyright protection?

Answer (score 1):

## Not TESmart HKS0802A1U

This is an anti-answer. I just found this post, looking for the same thing. I bought the [TESmart HKS0802A1U](https://www.tesmart.com/products/tesmart-hdmi-dual-monitor-kvm-switch4x2), it's advertised as *"4 Port Dual Monitor KVM Switch HDMI 4K60Hz with Cascading"* having a "Mixed Mode" (Display Mode 2) that supports "Criss-crossing Display" mode..

[image: Graphic from advertising]

However, it doesn't support it! In the Q/A on Amazon it says,

> It should be noted that when used in mixed screen mode, the outputA port displays the screen of the device connected to input A, and the outputB port displays the screen of the device connected to input B.

I wrote to them, and asked how do I get Criss-cross Display mode, assuming I have a Computer Foo and Computer Bar with two outputs/screen each, and two monitors.

- If I plug Foo's

  - Output A into Monitor 1 on Input 1 of KVM
  - Output B into Monitor 2 on Input 1 of the KVM
- If I plug Bar's

  - Output A into Monitor 1 on Input 2 of the KVM
  - Output B into Monitor 2 on Input 2 of the KVM.

Then in Mix Mode, I'll see

- Foo's Output A on Monitor 1
- Bar's Output B on Monitor 2

If I switch them though, I'll see

- Foo's Output B on Monitor 2
- Bar's Output A on Monitor 1

But this is not criss-crossing. Per the graphic, I would expect to see the same screen on Foo (Output A) in the above, move from Monitor 1 to Monitor 2. Not the other output (Output B) show on Monitor 2.

They responded and owned up to it,

> **Sorry, the Output A of the product you purchased (SKU: HKS0802A1U) can only display the image of Input A, and the Output B can only display the image of Input B, so this product cannot realize criss crossing display.**

So this doesn't do what you and I both want.